# c++ LinkedList when calling display function

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I"m trying to understand link list but every example I've tried to copy gives me a segmentation fault. This is my example program that I am working on.

in contacts.h

```
struct people{
  string last;
  string first;
  int age;
  people *next;
};

class Contacts {
 private:
  people *head;
 public:
  Contacts() {
   head=NULL;
  };
  void add(string, string, int);
  void display();
};
```

in main.cpp

```
//menu items
//cin >> option
//if option == 1, addContact
//if option == 8, displayContact
//basic in and out here no need to show code
```

in main.h

```
void addContact() {

  Contacts *ptr;     

  int i, loop=0, a=0;
  string l, f;

  cout << "number of contacts " << endl;
  cin >> loop;

  for(i=0; i<loop; i++) {

    cout << "enter last name ";
    cin >> l;

    cout << "enter first name ";
    cin >> f;

    cout << "enter age ";
    cin >> a;

  }

  ptr->add(l,f,a);

}
void display() {

 Contacts *ptr;
 ptr->display();
}
```

in contacts.cpp

```
void Contacts::add(string l, string f, int a) {

  people *node = new people;

  node->last=l;
  node->first=f;
  node->age=a;

  node->next=NULL;
}

void Contacts::display() {
 people *tmp = head;
 while(tmp!=NULL) {
   cout << tmp->last << endl;
   cout << tmp->first << endl;
   cout << tmp->age << endl;
   tmp->next;
 }
```

the add function works
then display() gives me a segfault

Comment: You may want this: `while(head!=NULL)` to be this:`while(tmp!=NULL)` instead. Considering nothing in that loop modifies `head`, you're going to be there awhile (at least until a crash, anyway). Not that it matters. `ptr->add(l,f,a);` invoked undefined behavior long before that. There are quite literally *thousands* of functional examples of linked lists on the web. Perhaps review a few.

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code. You should first try to build a simple linked list out of the struct people. Combine it with Contact class only after having implemented this. The cause of your error seems to be that head is not pointing to anything when you execute the while condition (Not even NULL, because you call it from an uninitialized pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member function add should be defined the following way

```
void Contacts::add( const string &l, const string &f, int a ) 
{
    head = new people { l, f, a, head };
}
```

Or if your compiler does not support initializer lists with the new operator then

```
void Contacts::add( const string &l, const string &f, int a ) 
{
    people *p = new people;

    p->last = l;
    p->first = f;
    p->age = a;
    p->next = head;

    head = p;
}
```

Member fuunction display should be declared as

```
void Contacts::display() const;
```

and defined as

```
void Contacts::display() const
{
    for ( people *tmp = head; tmp; tmp = tmp->next )
    {
        cout << tmp->last << endl;
        cout << tmp->first << endl;
        cout << tmp->age << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The other two functions should be defined the following way

```
void addContact( Contacts &contacts ) 
{
    int n = 0;

    cout << "number of contacts " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        string l, f;
        int a = 0;

        cout << "enter last name ";
        cin >> l;

        cout << "enter first name ";
        cin >> f;

        cout << "enter age ";
        cin >> a;

        contacts.add( l, f, a );
    }
}


void display( const Contacts &contacts ) 
{
    contacts.display();
}
```

And in main you should define an object of type

```
Contacts contacts;
```

and use it as the argument of the functions above.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped out a lot. I like people like you who actually help out without criticizing us novices. These people can learn much from you. Again thank you!